Does the current Use Case Diagram clearly represent how users interact with the system?
Detailed Idea for the Dermatech System

Main Idea of the System:
Dermatech is an AI-based system that operates through a mobile application, designed to assist users in diagnosing primary skin conditions and providing treatment recommendations. The system aims to simplify access to initial dermatological diagnoses while reducing the need for doctor visits unless necessary.

How the System Works:

Image Capture and Disease Diagnosis:

The user captures an image of the affected skin area using their smartphone camera through the app.
The image is sent to the application server, where a deep learning AI model analyzes it.
The model identifies the potential skin condition based on the training data it has received.

Asking Additional Questions for Confirmation:

After the initial diagnosis, the system asks specific questions (e.g., itchiness, pain, spread) to verify the diagnosis.
These questions are chosen based on a database containing symptoms related to dermatological diseases.

Providing the Final Diagnosis:

If the answers align with the initial diagnosis, the system provides the user with the final result and potential treatment recommendations (e.g., over-the-counter creams or medications).
If the symptoms do not match the expected disease, the app advises the user to consult a dermatologist for an accurate diagnosis.

The word "Mange" reads like a typo. Did you mean "Manage"?

Yes, you're right. I meant to write "Manage," but I spelled it incorrectly.

Use cases shall explain the purpose of the system independently of its internal structure and how it achieves in detail the purpose.  It is also not advised to use a use-case diagram for functional decomposition (see also Ivar Jacobson article on the evolution of use cases).
Keep the use-case diagram focused on the goals, and move everything where a there is some sequential order required to an activity diagram that describes more in detail the behaviors behind the use-case.
All what you need for your question is above.  nevertheless some hints to set in practice with examples:

"View home page" is a user interface detail.  Nobody uses a system just to see a home page.
"Manage accounts" should appear only once, even if different actors execute it.  The CRUD details are not necessary as they make it more complicated.
"View past diagnoses" deserves a plain use-case on its own. Anyway, it's not included in "Manage account": this is an independent usage. Keep in mind: the fact that a user interface navigates from account to past diagnosis, is not a reason for the UC to show this user interface detail.
Not sure that "Manage database" adds any value here.
Login/logout are not use cases but actions that belong to an activity diagram.
"Initial diagnosis" and "questions seem different steps in the "disease identification" and therefore better suited for an activity diagram describing the activity needed for the diagnosis.
It is not clear if the autonomous AI actor also does the prescription or not. Depending on your design intent, either add it to the activity diagram of the diagnosis, or keep it as a separate use-case with a Doctor as actor.


Thank you for your feedback and suggestions.
I have a question regarding your suggestion to merge the diagnosis-related steps These steps are currently separate but sequential, with interactions between the system and the user in each. Do you think it’s better to combine them into one use case (Identify Disease) or keep them separate since they involve distinct interactions? the role of the AI Model, it only identifies the disease and sends the result to the system. The medications are retrieved from the database and are not directly part of the AI’s output.

Interesting. So "Manage database" is meant to manage the medications for possible diseases?  In this case keep that UC but make it more specific.  Out of curiosity, does your database also deal with allergies to the medication or incompatibilities with other medications that the patient already takes for other purposes?

Regarding potential merge, the two possibilities are open:  you could have a UC "diagnosis and prescription" and AI actor would be involved even if it doesn't do it all.  You could even merge in it the capture, and associate user to "diagnosis and prescription. An activity diagram would describe the different steps.

Although I'm not a fan of it, you could alternatively use «include» not to show the sequence but the subgoals with involvement of different actors.  Capture image would be included in it,  diagnosis (but without going into its steps)  and get medication presciption.

@ShahadAt, a use-case diagram is basically a graphical table-of-contents for why actors would want to use the system. Anything that hints at a how or what does not have a place in a use-case diagram.

@Christophe I haven’t decided on that yet, but for now, the medications that will be displayed don’t require a doctor’s prescription and can be purchased directly from the pharmacy.

@ShahadAt - Also, actors are meant to represent users (or rather, their roles), or supporting services external to the system. If the AI model isn't considered a separate, external (possibly 3rd party) service that your system makes use of, then it shouldn't be an actor, as it is just another part of the system itself. So it'd be covered by a UC named something like "Submit image for initial diagnosis."

P.S. Depending on the description of the associated use case, as depicted, the role of the AI actor could either be interpreted as that of an external agent that either just orchestrates the process, without having diagnostic capabilities itself (your system does), or as a supporting external system with diagnostic capabilities that your system does not itself possess.

@FilipMilovanović This is completely exact. This is  why in the last bullet I referred to an "autonomous AI actor", suggesting therewith an external model that exists on its own.  considering it is a supporting role that a human could in theory also play, the actor would be suitable.

@Christophe - ah, sorry - I didn't read all the way through. I was focused on trying to parse OPs description in the question, and couldn't shake the feeling that the OP represented the AI as an actor almost by default because it's "an intelligence".

@FilipMilovanović no need to be sorry ;-) It's a constructive remark on an important point that I did not develop too much because of my own assumptions. I added a link to highlight the "autonomous" with an other answer where I explain more in detail the principle.
